# How do you detect if there is an index for a specific column on a table in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, indexing

A table exists that someone else loaded.  I need to query against the table, but the lack of indexes makes the query plan abysmal.  What I would like to do is detect if there is an index for a particular column, so that I can created it if it does not exist, and not create it if it is already there.

Thanks.

Evil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can query `DBA_/ALL_/USER_IND_COLUMNS`, i.e.

```
SQL> SELECT index_name
  2    FROM dba_ind_columns
  3   WHERE table_owner = 'SCOTT'
  4     AND table_name  = 'EMP'
  5     AND column_name = 'EMPNO';

INDEX_NAME
------------------------------
PK_EMP
```

Of course, you may want to expand the query a bit.  This will pick up any index that the EMPNO column appears in.  You may want to limit yourself to indexes where the column is the leading column of the index (`COLUMN_POSITION` = 1).  Or you may want to limit yourself to indexes just on that particular column (so that there is no column in `COLUMN_POSITION` 2), i.e.

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  SELECT index_name
  2    FROM dba_ind_columns a
  3   WHERE table_owner = 'SCOTT'
  4     AND table_name  = 'EMP'
  5     AND column_name = 'EMPNO'
  6     AND column_position = 1
  7     AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
  8                       FROM dba_ind_columns b
  9                      WHERE a.index_owner = b.index_owner
 10                        AND a.index_name  = b.index_name
 11*                       AND b.column_position = 2)
SQL> /

INDEX_NAME
------------------------------
PK_EMP
```

Answer (score 2):

Become familiar with querying the SYS schema:

```
Select * from sys.all_ind_columns where table_name=:TabName and table_owner=:TabOwner;
```